# ChartJS 6.2 - fillText() always uses last ctx.font settings

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Ultimate goal I have is to write text to the center of Doughnut chart, using ChartJS library, with having different portions of text using different font params.

Now, adding text to the center of doughnut chart is not an issue. The problem I'm having is that all `fillText()` are using the last `ctx.font` values.

Note that this works without any problems using older versions of ChartJS.

Working example( old version of lib ): https://jsfiddle.net/os2L3e5b/
Working example( ChartJS 6.2 ): http://jsfiddle.net/qu4ztg8m/8/

So, in the http://jsfiddle.net/qu4ztg8m/8/, I am creating two plugins that are just drawing on canvas, in different colors.

Again, the point is that I can add multiple pieces of text using different fonts.

Comment: You have to use `normal` not `regular` (see [css fonts spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts/#valdef-font-weight-normal)). Not important, but since it's in the title, you're using charts.js version 4.3.0, (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) where did you get the 6.2 value from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should include your context 2D statement saving and restoring the context (in2 plugins) as following:

```
                ctx.save(); // saves previous config
                ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";
                ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 255,1)';
                ctx.fillText( 20, 70, 130 );
                ctx.restore(); // restores previous config
```

Plugin:

```
var chartjs_draw_in_doughnut_plugin = {
  afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart, args, options) {
    // Get ctx from string
    const ctx = chart.ctx;
    // saves the state of the canvas
    ctx.save();
    // ------------
    // FIRST LABEL
    // ------------
    // creates new path to draw something with the same config
    ctx.beginPath();
    // sets config  
    ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 255,1)';
    ctx.fillText( 20, 70, 130 );
    // fills text
    ctx.fill();
    // ------------
    // SECOND LABEL
    // ------------
    // creates new path to draw something with the same config
    ctx.beginPath();
    // sets config  
    ctx.font = "regular 16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 255,0.5)';
    ctx.fillText( ' / 50', 85, 130 );
    // fills text
    ctx.fill();
    // restores the state of the canvas
    ctx.restore();
  }
}
```

Comment: This fixes it. Can you please elaborate a tad more? Also, there's some weird stuff happening. When I combine the two codes in one plugin, it works. If I then remove second save, it will respect ctx.font but not ctx.fillText properties

Comment: I have played with you sample, joining 2 plugins but also having 2, and it's working well. What is not working?

Comment: I said when I remove second ctx.save(); Basically, I just wanted to understand what's going on, how that works and why.

Comment: Updated answer adding the plugin. For more info how to manage states and paths, have a lok to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath